# Как работать с датой в golang?

Tags: golang

Простите за нубство, но накак не могу освоить дату. Читал тут https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time
Любой из вариантов выдаёт ошибки

```
t := time.Date(year int, month Month, day)
t := time.Date(year, month, day)
t := func Now()
t := Now()
```

При такой комбинации:

```
t := time.Now()
fmt.Printf(t)
```

Вроде всё верно но он говорит что не могу использовать t как строку как аргумент функции fmt.Printf

Дата вообще в какому типу относится? Если я создам `var := "2017-12-22"` то она очевидно будет строковго типа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип Time - это [структура со скрытыми полями](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time). Вы в самом деле не можете использовать её как строку, но зная что `Time` соответствует [интерфейсу `Stringer`](https://tour.golang.org/methods/17), вы можете привести время к строке явно или косвенно:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main () {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t.String())
    fmt.Printf("Сейчас: %s\n", t)
}
```

[Выполнить этот код](https://play.golang.org/p/MHucJADKU4)

Первым аргументом к `fmt.Printf` должна быть строка [по определению функции](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf); если вы туда пытаетесь дать объект, то естественно ничего не работает.

Comment: Спасибо, я только не могу понять почему просто fmt.Printf(tnow) не работает а fmt.Printf("Сейчас: %s\n", tnow) работает?

Comment: первым аргументом к `fmt.Printf` должна быть строка [по определению функции](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf); если вы туда пытаетесь дать объект, то естественно ничего не работает